# Weird mouseover behavior in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, mouseover

We have a heading element styled as:

```
<div class="sidebarHeadingFont">Operation</div>

.sidebarHeadingFont {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color: #003366; }
```

In Chrome when you put your mouse over this element the font size increases (making the width of the element bigger) and the color changes to white.  Why is this??  Doesn't do this in IE or Firefox.

Comment: Probably you have some unclosed tags, or have a link to other css stylesheet in meta. Use W3 validation and if it doesn't help post rest of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really, really sure you don't have any other css and/or html? Cause it sounds really, really strange..

Comment: Yes I was being a bonehead.  We also had `.sidebarHeadingFont:hover       {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; }`